# Slider based on buttons on wp site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want a new slider images when the radio button are clicked
but somehow it keeps images from old selection and concatenate with the new ones.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        var count = 0;
        var image = $('#pg-48-0> .panel-row-style');

        if (this.value == 'camping') {
            var images={};   
            images = [ "http://development.tripoutside.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/camping.jpg"];
        }
        else if (this.value == 'road-sports') {
            var images={};
            images = [ "http://development.tripoutside.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bikes.jpg",
                       "http://development.tripoutside.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bike2.jpg",
                       "http://development.tripoutside.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/bike3.jpg"];
        }
        else if (this.value == 'snow-sports') {
        }
        else if (this.value == 'water-sports') {
        }

        setInterval(function(){
            image.css("background-image","url("+images[count++]+")");

            if(count == images.length)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        },5000);

    });
});

</script>
```

Here is the link to site: http://development.tripoutside.com/

Comment: To set css property you should write $(images).css(). Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the var statement inside the if-clauses does not give the effect you want. images has been declared within the function already.
My first try would be to declare images only once and leave the extra declarations out.